# How to write the pseudocode of algorithm for finding a connected undirected graph with minimal average graph clustering coefficient?

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode

I need an algorithm or pseudo-code for finding a connected undirected graph with minimal average graph clustering coefficient for any e (edges) and n (nodes). What will be the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: I think you are better off asking this question on cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: "I am searching the code but could not find it". Perhaps you could write code rather than "search for it".

Comment: Learn the concept and write the code.